# Thumbnail not creating with Galaxy S4

Tags: android, arrays, thumbnails, android-camera-intent

I have an activity where in I give the user an option to click an image from the camera, then I store this image in a byte array and in the Database.

**Problem** - However my code does not seem to work on Samsung Galaxy S4 while creating thumbnail.Below is the code:

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new             AlertDialog.Builder(FeedbackActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {

                    String BX1 =  android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;



                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);


                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                onCaptureVideoResult(data);

            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a different approach as explained in this [post](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/)

While invoking the camera app, you need to specify the path using

> intent.PutExtra (MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile (App._file));

In the way, the captured image will be saved to the above location and
in onActivityResult method, you can access the same file and do further processing.

Hope this helps.